# "Change Source Control" not in menu - Team Foundation Server 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm seeking to repair bindings between Visual Studio and TFS (both 2010) and have done my searching. The pages I sought help from are:
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfs/ms181375(v=vs.100).aspx
    [Can't unbind solution from Team Foundation Server 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142671/cant-unbind-solution-from-team-foundation-server-2010)

They all say the following:
"On the File menu, click Source Control, and then click Change Source Control", however no such sub-menu exists in my Visual Studio (2010) installation in the "Source Control" sub-menu. I've ensured that the correct project is selected in the Source Control Explorer.

Please help me overcome this nightmare!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue.  Even with the solution open, I still couldn't see `Change Source Control`.

What it seems to be, a bit bizarrely, was that I had the solution selected in Solution Explorer.  If I selected any other item in the Solution Explorer (e.g. any file) I could then go to `File -> Source Control -> Advanced -> Change Source Control...` and rebind everything from there.

Maybe it was that I had an item selected that, as far as Visual Studio was concerned, didn't have any source control bindings, so it didn't show the option to change them.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of selecting the solution in the Source Control Explorer, you need to open the solution/project so it displays in the Solution Explorer.  Once it is there, the menu item will display.  The only way I couldn't get "Change Source Control" to display, is to not have the solution open.

Mike